# System can't find pip

Tags: python, pip

I first installed Spyder and then afterwards Python on a server (with Windows Server 2019) all on the directory C:\Users\wi932. Now I want to use the command prompt to install packages (e.g. tensorflow) but unfortunately I get the error message that "the command pip is either wrongly written or can't be found "(translated). I am wondering why I get this error because on my normal laptop I type in the exact same commands and there everything is okay.

I have attached a screenshot of the command prompt. I tried to install the packages both in the spyder folder ( C:\Users\wi932.spyder-py3) and the Python folder ( C:\Users\wi932\Python\Python310). I always get the same error.

Does anyone of you have an idea what the problem might be and how to fix it? I'll appreciate every comment.

[image: Screenshot command prompt Windows]

Comment: The directory `Python310` should contain the directory `Scripts` where `pip` is located.

Comment: @MichaelO.: Thanks for the command. Now pip can be found. However, it can't install many packages. While for some packages it is okay. For others I get errors. E.g when trying "pip install tensorflow" I get the error "pip install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow". Or when trying "C:\Users\wi9632\Python\Python310\Scripts>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.4.3.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:"

Comment: @MichaelO.: Is there maybe a way to directly import the packages to spyder? I only use Spyder for Python so it would be totally enough to use these packages only in Spyder (and no other Python environment like jupyter).

Comment: Try to install Python 3.8 or 3.9. To avoid problems with `pip`, on the first window of the installation program there is a checkbox `Add Python to PATH`.

Comment: @MichaelO.: Thanks for your comment. I did exactly what you suggested. I installed the latest version of Python (after deleting the old version) and I set the checkbox "Add Python to Path". However, the problems still remain the same. When trying to install tensorflow or matplotlib I get the same error messages.

Comment: 3.8 or 3.9 is not the latest. Some packages have no version for the latest (3.10) Python distro. I'm using 3.8 currently.

Comment: @MichaelO.: Thanks a lot for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Basically I tried what you suggested and now in fact I can install all the packages using pip. However, Spyder does not find those packages altough I installed them. Whenenver I call one of the installed modules form Spyder I get an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'". So the question is how can I build a "connection" between the pip and Spyder?

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything about Spyder :)

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it (if you write an answer I will upvote and accept it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory containing `pip` is located in `<Python directory>\Scripts`. To make Windows find it, you need to check the "Add Python to PATH" checkbox during installation.

Some packages, including `tensorflow`, have no version for the last Python distro, so you need to "downgrade" it by installing an older version, for example, 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing python in local download it at [www.python.org](http://www.python.org) then you can run any command with pip directly in local

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Augustin. What do you mean by local? Basically I am using a server with multiple users